# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Tags: command-line

If I run a non-existing command in the terminal (as for example `lasdfese` or `vlsefoserlks`) I get the output below. Why? How to get back to normal behaviour? I could add that this happend after updating to python3.8, and that I am using ubuntu 18.04.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 28, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 19, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.db import SqliteDatabase
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/db.py", line 5, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 24, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 28, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 19, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.db import SqliteDatabase
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/db.py", line 5, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I resolved it.

There is a python script called `command-not-found` in `/usr/lib/command-not-found`.

This script, gets updated after you upgrade your python version. At least that's what happened to me. I upgraded from Python3.6 to Python3.8.

Now, the issue is, This script is working based on the previous version of Python.
So I went into this file, and changed the first line from

`#!/usr/bin/python3` (which refers to python3.8)

to:

`#!/usr/bin/python3.6` (which is python version comes with Ubuntu 18.04)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error with the "ubuntu-drivers devices" command. Inspired by the @flowfelis' answer, I updated python version and it resolved the problem.

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config python3
There are 2 choices for the alternative python3 (providing /usr/bin/python3).

  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/python3.7   2         auto mode
* 1            /usr/bin/python3.7   2         manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/python3.8   1         manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 2
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/python3.8 to provide /usr/bin/python3 (python3) in manual mode
```