# "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'" appears in various commands

Tags: python, python3

I get the following error in various situations, for example when I try to start a package that is not installed:

```
   $ tldr
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 28, in <module>
        from CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 19, in <module>
        from CommandNotFound.db.db import SqliteDatabase
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/db.py", line 5, in <module>

    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 24, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 28, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 19, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.db import SqliteDatabase
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/db.py", line 5, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
```

I've tried the solution in [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190328/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-apt-pkg) but that didn't help.
I've also tried installing and reinstalling different versions of python, and change the update-alternatives links.
I suspect that I somehow ruined the configuration of the python the OS uses.

Some general info:

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="KDE neon"
VERSION="5.18"
ID=neon
ID_LIKE="ubuntu debian"
PRETTY_NAME="KDE neon User Edition 5.18"
VARIANT="User Edition"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="http://neon.kde.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://neon.kde.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.kde.org/"
LOGO=start-here-kde-neon
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

python2:

```
$ update-alternative s --config python
    There is only one alternative in link group python (providing /usr/bin/python): /usr/bin/python2.7
    Nothing to configure.

$ python --version
Python 2.7.17
```

python3:

```
$ update-alternatives --config python3
There is only one alternative in link group python3 (providing /usr/bin/python3): /usr/bin/python3.7
Nothing to configure.

$ python3 --version
Python 3.7.5
```

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a KDE/Neon forum.

Comment: Thanks @guiverc, I published it in https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/588066/412597 now instead. Let me know if I should delete this question then or just ignore if not.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make sure that python-apt has been installed.
you can remove and reinstall python3-apt.
try:

```
sudo apt install python3-apt --fix-missing
```

or

```
sudo apt remove python3-apt
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt install python3-apt
```

maybe below code better than previous for remove python3-apt

```
sudo apt remove --purge python3-apt
```

you can use apt-get instead of apt.
I hope it helps you.

Comment: fix-missing didn't, but reinstalling as you suggested worked! Thanks!

Comment: your welcome @gal

Comment: The second solution works for me.

Comment: Worked for me too.  Thanks.

Comment: idem second solution works!